# Add a custom content block within an existing content block of Magento Core

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add a custom order attribute, that the user can define on the checkout page just after the list of the payment methods and before the button continue.

I want to do things as clean as possible, so I created my own module.

Im struggling with  something I thought it would be simple but I don't succeed to find a solution.

At the moment I only need to be able to display the template file in the following block .

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment
```

I created my template file which is only displaying a stupid text for the test
app/design/defaut/defaut/template/mymodule/custom.phtml
I know that there is no problem with this file while I used it on the index action of my module

I think the main issue is that I must not do properly the xml layout declaration.

Maybe you can help me

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
<!-- this part is working well -->
        <mymodule_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </mymodule_index_index>
<!-- this part is not working at all -->
        <checkout_onepage_index>
            <reference="checkout.onepage.payment" >
                <block type="core/template" name="mymodule"  template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_index>
    </layout>
```

Of course my module is well declared as the index method of my module is working.
is it my reference tag which is not good ?

Thanks in advance, this layout organisation gives me headache,

Best,

Anselme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As b.enoit.be noted, you forgot the name attribute. Besides that, you also need to echo out your block. This is your update:

```
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.payment" >
            <block type="core/template" name="mymodule"  template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
```

Your block is declared as a child of checkout.onepage.payment, which also has another child block (checkout.payment.methods) and this block is echoed out in the checkout.onepage.payment template (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml):

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What you need to do is echo out your block some where in the checkout.onepage.payment block's template, such as:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule') ?>
```

Comment: thanks david, really helps. However what would be the cleanest way to to override  checkout.onepage.payment template in a custom module so that it implemented in every design ?

Comment: The base package templates really shouldn't be modified. Likewise with the default theme of a package. Make a copy of app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml and put in your theme; i.e. app/design/frontend/rwd/[YOUR_THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml.

Comment: Thanks david, the things is I develop it as the module and not a specific theme I would like to be implemtened by defaut when , in any theme if this part of design has not be modified,if someone install the module. I was thinking of copy/pasting the base file payment.html in the folder app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.html, it don't know what would be the best practice to respect and when you have some custom block frontend in a custom module

Comment: Actually this is a very common problem, how to add a child block when there's a dependency on the parent block. If parent was core/text_list, then there's no problem. I don't recommend customizing and redistributing payment.phtml since it's a core template, and updates and different Magento versions may invalidate your customized payment.phtml. There are a number of workarounds to this problem, for example observing core_block_abstract_to_html_after of a child block and then appending your block html to that html. Another work around is overriding the payment block.

Comment: allright, thanks for your tips David, I will probably go with the observer method and I already did some observer and it seems to be less risky that overriding the payment block.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a problem in the reference, you are missing the attribute name which is mistyped there : `<reference="checkout.onepage.payment" >`

```
<reference name="checkout.onepage.payment" >
    <block type="core/template" name="mymodule"  template="mymodule/custom.phtml" />
</reference>
```